# Duda con formulario que se ejecuta en la misma página PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una página web en PHP que muestra un aviso y mas abajo los usuarios pueden hacer consultas sobre el producto que vende. Cuando se carga hace lo siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
require '../../includes/conexion.php';
include '../../includes/funcs_pdo.php';
include_once("../../includes/analyticstracking.php");

$codigo = base64_decode($_REQUEST['var']);

$conexion = new Conexion();
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT T1.id, T1.titulo, T2.detalle as detalle2, T1.disponibles, T1.vendidos, T1.localizacion, T1.detalle, T1.foto, T1.precio, T1.forma_pago, T1.email, T1.telefono, T1.usuario, T1.idusuario, T1.lecturas FROM avisos as T1 INNER JOIN avisos_rubros as T2 ON T1.rubro = T2.id WHERE T1.id = :valor");
$stmt->bindParam(':valor', $codigo);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$idUsuarioVendedor = $row['idusuario'];

?>
```

El problema que tengo es que mas abajo tengo el clásico textarea con un boton donde el usuario hace la pregunta, todo eso dentro de un form que por post quiero enviarlo a la misma pagina. Mi duda es donde coloco el código de dicho post ? a continuación de eso ? o antes de ese codigo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de ambas maneras, pero si quieres usar el valor de `$idUsuarioVendedor` en alguna parte de tu HTML, lo lógico sería poner el formulario después. Además, debieras verificar si se envió por POST la variable `var`

```
<?php
// acá los includes 
if(isset($_POST['var']) {

    $codigo = base64_decode($_POST['var']);
    // acá tu query
    $idUsuarioVendedor = $row['idusuario'];

}
?>
<form method="POST">
...
</form>
```

Comment: genial... muchas gracias !!!